# Symfony 2 PUGXAutoCompleterBundle

Tags: php, symfony, autocomplete

I am trying to use : https://github.com/PUGX/PUGXAutoCompleterBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md

But the ajax request search_books, return an error :

```
The controller must return a response (Array(results => Array(0=>Object,1=>Object,...) given
```

I guess the problem come from `return compact('results');` but I can't find how to fix it.

Thanks for reading.
M

Comment: seem like you must define a twig template in your controller method, can you show your code? Are you using the twig listed in the readme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the doc is not specified how the template is render (missing annotations?).

I suppose you must add the right template annotation for the correct twig and manage the JSON response correctly.

I use this bundle and in my controller I render the data as:

```
/**
 * @Route("/autocomplete-user/search", name="acme_autocomplete_user_search")
 */
public function autocompleteUserSearchAction(Request $request)
{
    $q = $request->get('term');
    $userRepository = $this->get('acme.user_provider');
    $users = $userRepository->findLikeUsername($q);

    $results = array();
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $results[] = array(
            'id' => $user->getId(),
            'name' => $user->getFullName(),
            'label' => sprintf("[%s] %s", $user->getUsername(), $user->getFullName())
        );
    }

    return new JsonResponse($results);
}
```

and the other method is:

```
/**
 * @Route("/autocomplete-user/{id}", name="acme_autocomplete_user_get")
 */
public function autocompleteUserGetAction($id)
{
    $userRepository = $this->get('acme.user_provider');
    $user = $userRepository->find($id);

    return new Response($user->getUsername());
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Hi @MatMouth! You're welcome!  Think about to open a pull request on the doc of the bundle for clarify for better usage

Answer (score 1):

This bundle is really badly documented.

What Matteo said in the previous post is right if you are usisng Jquery-UI library. Is you wanna use Select2 library, you have to modify the code this way:

```
/**
 * @Route("/autocomplete-user/search", name="acme_autocomplete_user_search")
 */
public function autocompleteUserSearchAction(Request $request)
{
    $q = $request->get('q');
    $userRepository = $this->get('acme.user_provider');
    $users = $userRepository->findLikeUsername($q);

    $results = array();
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $results[] = array(
            'id' => $user->getId(),
            'text' => $user->getFullName())
        );
    }

    return new JsonResponse($results);
}
```

please note that the attribut i not "term" anymore but "q"

please note that for Select2 lib the default Json response format is the following :

```
{
 more: false,
 results: [
    { id: "CA", text: "California" },
    { id: "AL", text: "Alabama" }
    ]
}
```

but in PUGXAutoCompleterBundle it expect only :

```
[ { id: "CA", text: "California" },
      { id: "AL", text: "Alabama" } ]
```

In addition, no supported version is mentionned in the doc. it works fine for me with:
jquery 1.11.3 and jquery-ui 1.11.3
or
jquery1.11.3 ans select2 3.5.2

Hope that can save you time